# jQuery read table row

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table and I need to read a row and get all the ex. th. I wrote something like this, but it gives me the same array twice `['id','test']`.

How should I do this? As I have to process each `th` in php class to build a table.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var table = $("table");
        var headerCells = table.find("thead th");
        var headers = [];

        //get header cells
        headerCells.each(function(i) {
            i = $(this).text();
            headers[headers.length] = i;
        });

        //convert array to json
        var jsonArray = JSON.stringify(headers);

        //prepare POST data
        var dataToPost = { 'jsonArray':jsonArray };

        console.log(headers);

        $.ajax({ url: '/js/call.php',
            data: {data: dataToPost},
            type: 'get',
            success: function(output) {
                //output = eval( '(' + output + ')' );
                alert (output);
            }
        });
    });    //end jQ
</script>
```

Comment: Where do you get the array twice?

Comment: I'm very sorry ... I found a mistake ... while I was testing Michas's code. The problem is elsewhere - (I made 2 calls) I should get the rows of the table with jQuery within a PHP class. Still I don't know how to do that (now I made a call inside class to another php file) and then I have to process data with another class. Do someone of you know if it is possible make a call and get variables within a class - let's say with another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the ajax request

```
//prepare POST data
var dataToPost = { 'jsonArray':jsonArray };

console.log(headers);
$.ajax({ url: '/js/call.php',
        data: {data: dataToPost},
        type: 'get',
        success: function(output) {
            alert(output);
        }
    });
```

dataToPost is an object but string is expected, solution:

```
//prepare POST data
var dataToPost = { 'jsonArray':jsonArray };

console.log(headers);
$.ajax({ url: '/js/call.php',
        data: dataToPost,
        type: 'get',
        success: function(output) {
            alert(output);
        }
    });
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fm3TY/1/)

Answer (score 1):

your probably need to change this:

```
headerCells.each(function(i) {
    i = $(this).text();
    headers[headers.length] = i;
});
```

into

```
headerCells.each(function(idx, elm) {
    var text = $(elm).text();
    headers[idx] = text;
});
```

Comment: have you tested it? its wrong in that part of the code is no error

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something strange when you create the array

```
   //get header cells
    headerCells.each(function(i) {
        i = $(this).text();
        headers[headers.length] = i;
    });
```

i'd do:

```
   //get header cells
    headerCells.each(function(i) {
        i = $(this).text();
        headers.push(i);
    });
```

Comment: have you tested it? its wrong in that part of the code is no error